# ¿Se puede usar el valor de una variable dentro de una función para usarla en otra función? PHP

Tags: php, ajax, funciones, variables

Tengo dos funciones dentro de una clase, en una función tengo una consulta que agrupa géneros; cada vez que elijan un género con la función *OnClick* con el método AJAX, quiero que me muestre los elementos que tienen ese género debajo. ¿Puedo usar el valor guardado en la función para usarlo en otra? ó ¿hay alguna otra solución?, he intentado de muchas formas aún usando JavaScript.

Aclaro que el código sólo es un ejemplo de como es el código original.

Más o menos el código es así:

```
class Clase_A
{

function __construct()
{
    require"conexion.php";
    $this->conexion = $conexion;    
}
function Funcion_A()
{
    $consulta = mysqli_query($this->conexion, "SELECT DISTINCT genero FROM tabla");
//Ciclo para todos lo géneros que hayan.
    foreach($consulta as $elementos)
    {
    $genero = $elementos['genero'];
 //Muestra un botón con los géneros que dirige a la carpeta que contiene el género respectivo con el método AJAX.
    echo "<a onclick='cargarGenero(\"carpeta/". $genero . ".php\") href='#'>" . $genero . " </a>";
    }
}
function Funcion_B()
{
//Quisiera que la variable _$genero_ tuviese el valor de la función anterior.
    $consulta2 = mysqli_query($this->conexion, "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE genero = '$genero'");

    foreach($consulta2 as $elementos2)
    {
     echo "$elementos2['nombre']";
     echo "$elementos2['genero']";
    }
}
}
```

**Función AJAX para mostrar los elementos que tengan el género**

```
function cargarGenero(archive) 
{
    $.ajax({
       url:archive,
       success:function(resultado)
       {
         $("#listaGeneros").html(resultado)
       }
    })
}
```

**Código donde muestra los géneros:**

```
<div>
<?php  
    include("funciones.php");
//Llama a la Clase_A desde un archivo externo.
    $objeto = new Clase_A;
//Llama a la función dentro de la Clase_A
    $objeto -> Funcion_A();
?>
</div>
<div id="listaGeneros">


</div>
```

Comment: Puedes publicar tu codigo ajax y html?

Comment: Los cambios se hicieron, y el supongo que ése es el código que pediste.

Comment: @user74978 puedes guardar el valor de $genero en una variable global

Comment: Eso ya lo he intentado. Al introducirlo como variable global y llamarlo en la función no lo toma con el valor de la función anterior.
Gracias por tu comentario y sugerencia.

Comment: @user74978 la instrucción $objeto -> Funcion_B();   será llamada después de $objeto -> Funcion_A(); ? Me refiero a: en la misma petición.

Comment: @crrlos Para nada, la Funcion_B se llama en un archivo a parte donde muestra toda la información de la tabla. La Funcion_A sólo mostrará los géneros sugeridos

Comment: @user74978 en la función cargarGenero(archive) podrías pasarle como parámetro el ID del género , quedando así: cargarGenero(archive,ID). Luego, enviar ese parámetro ID en la petición ajax y recibir el parámetro en el archivo php y usarlo dentro Funcion_B().

Comment: @crrlos Perdón, no entiendo qué quieres decir; ¿quieres decir esto?, que el código quede así:


function cargarGenero(archive, id) 
{
    $.ajax({
       url:archive, 
       id,
       success:function(resultado)
       {
         $("#listaGeneros").html(resultado)
       }
    })
}

Y llamar a la función como 
$objeto = new Class_A;
$objeto -> Funcion_B(id);

¿Así?

Perdón si acá queda muy desordenado.

Comment: No entiendo por que mandas a llamar un php dentro una carpeta, pero voy a tratar de hacer un codigo para que entiendas la logica.

Comment: @IsmaelMartinez Si te refieres a la Funcion_A en el echo del foreach es para que sea más organizado. En el código original hay un código que verifica que si hay un género nuevo, agregue el archivo dentro de ésa carpeta con el nombre del nuevo género e igualmente muestre los elementos que contengan ése genero. Es un código de automatización para evitar complique con el usuario y el cliente.

Comment: No termino de entender... Pero quiero decir que la recomendación de usar una variable global para esto no es recomendable, sería una mala práctica. Al ver tus dos consultas casi iguales no entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer y hasta hace pensar que todo se podría resolver en una sola consulta. Más aún sabiendo que al ser una petición Ajax no puedes ejecutar el código PHP en dos partes desde la misma llamada. Para mí el problema principal es que no terminas de razonar, de explicar de forma clara y sencilla lo que pretendes hacer y eso conduce muchas veces en programación a errores de lógica.

Comment: Voy a explicar lo que quiero hacer con un ejemplo que todo deben haberse relacionado en algún momento.
¿Han visto en google imágenes que debajo del buscador aparecen sugerencias?; es bastante simple, sólo busco que me muestre las sugerencias y al efectuar el evento _OnClick_ sobre una de ellas, me pase la consulta de sólo ése género; pero sin tener que recargar la página y que me lo muestre en una tabla justo debajo de los género.

Les agradezco sus opiniones, y sus comentarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Espero haber entendido bien):

Con `Funcion_A` muestras una lista de géneros y al hacer click en uno se debe traer el contenido correspondiente a ese género en particular ejecutando `Funcion_B` mediante una consulta ajax.

Entonces, lo que yo haría sería algo como esto:

En `Funcion_A`, modificaría el valor que se envía a la función `cargarGenero()`, proporcionándole directamente lo que luego se va a usar en `Funcion_B`:

```
function function Funcion_A()
{
    // ...
    echo "<a onclick='cargarGenero($genero) href='#'>" . $genero . " </a>";
    // ...
}
```

En `Funcion_B`, agregamos el parámetro `$genero` que se va a usar en la consulta SQL:

```
function Funcion_B($genero)
{
    // ...
}
```

Luego, en `cargarGenero`, mediante ajax enviar ese valor a un archivo encargado exclusivamente de obtener la información (`cargar_genero.php`):

```
function cargarGenero(genero) 
{
    $.get(
       'cargar_genero.php',
       { genero: genero },
       function(resultado)
       {
         $('#listaGeneros').html(resultado);
       },
       'html'
    );
}
```

Por último, en `cargar_genero.php`, buscar la información del género especificado y devolver el resultado:

```
<?php
require 'funciones.php';

$genero = $_GET['genero'];

$objeto = new Clase_A;
$objeto->Funcion_B($genero);
```

Por ahí pasé algo por alto, pero creo que funcionaría ^_^

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte. Lo había intentado de ésa forma antes pero no me funcionaba por que el índice 'genero' no se define por lo que no toma el valor que deseo que tome
Pero tu método me ha funcionado de maravilla, muchas gracias. He logrado hacer lo que quería con el aporte que me diste. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro de haber podido ayudar! :D

Answer (score 0):

Mi recomendación es que crear propiedades en tu clase y ahí guardes los datos que quieras imprimir para imprimirlos en un tercer método en tu clase (recuerda que las funciones dentro declases se llaman métodos).

Pero para salir pronto del embrollo te recomiendo que metas las dos consultas dentro de un sólo método, tu clase quedaría así:

```
function Funcion_A()
    {
        $consulta = mysqli_query($this->conexion, "SELECT DISTINCT genero FROM tabla");
        //Ciclo para todos lo géneros que hayan.
        foreach($consulta as $elementos)
        {
            $genero = $elementos['genero'];

            $consulta2 = mysqli_query($this->conexion, "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE genero = '$genero'");

            //Muestra un botón con los géneros que dirige a la carpeta que contiene el género respectivo con el método AJAX.
            echo "<a onclick='cargarGenero(\"carpeta/". $genero . ".php\") href='#'>" . $genero . " </a>";
            foreach($consulta2 as $elementos2)
            {
                echo "$elementos2['nombre']";
                echo "$elementos2['genero']";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu sugerencia; es la manera más simple de hacerlo; pero lo que busco es interactividad, que la primera consulta muestre los género y al llamarla el evento _OnClick_ me muestre los elementos del género que se ha elegido que muestra la segunda consulta.